# Method hiding plus overriding calling decision

Tags: c#, overriding, method-hiding

In case of method overriding based on the type referent object hold method call will be decided.
In case of method hiding based on type of object method call will be decided.

Can any one explain me the method calling decision in overriding + hiding.

```
public class Base
    {
        public virtual void DoIt()
        {
        }
    }

    public class Derived : Base
    {
        public  override void DoIt()
        {
        }
    }

    public class Derived1 : Derived
    {
        public new void DoIt()
        {
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Base b = new Derived();
            Derived d = new Derived();
      #1    b.DoIt();                      // Calls Derived.DoIt
      #2    d.DoIt();                     // Calls Derived.DoIt
            b = new Derived1();
            d = new Derived1();
      #3    b.DoIt();                      // Calls Derived.DoIt
      #4    d.DoIt();
}
}
```

#1 and #2 call Derived.DoIt because of run-time polymorphism.

#4 called  Derived.DoIt because d is of type Dreived (Method hiding).

But why #3 called Derived.DoIt.

What is the calling sequence in case of overiding plus hiding in c#.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can think of it like this: `Derived1` has two `DoIt` methods - one inherited from `Base` class, and another declared right in `Derived1` itself. When you call DoIt on instances of type Base or Derived - they know only about one DoIt method and no idea about the other, so this one is getting called.

Answer (score 1):

Because #3 is an instance of `Base` type. Here, the last derived method of `Base` resides in `Derived` class and hence it is being called.

`new` / method hiding / shadowing is different than method overriding in the sense that override means that you are customizing the base method whereas `new` means you are just providing a different implementation for the same method name.

Answer (score 1):

In Method overriding it is decided on run-time which type's method to be called, but method hiding or shadowing is compile time thing, the compiler knows at compile time that which type's method is to called, when you use `new` keyword in derived type in method signature instead of override, that means that if you will call using reference of base class it will call base class implementation and if you use derived class reference it will call derived class method implementation.

The derived class implementation get's hidden from base class.

If you write it like this:

```
b = new Derived1();
b.DoIt() // (run-time) will call Dervied method implementation as Dervied has overridden 
        // so calling via base reference will call overridden implementation if any
       //otherwise base class implementation will get called

Derived1 d1 = (Derived1)b;
d1.DoIt(); // (compile time) will call Derived1 method implementation due to hiding in Derived1
Derived d = (Derived)b;
d.DoIt(); // (run-time) will call Derived method implementation due to override
```

Answer (score 0):

#3 calls Derived.DoIt() because the method was only hidden, it is still externally callable if using the appropriate cast. The variable b of is of type Base, and so you are accessing the methods available to Base. This is the one that is overwritten via Derived, so your result is the one from Derived.DoIt. Would you have a variable of type Derived1 and did a call to DoIt there, Derived1.DoIt would have been called instead.

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual void DoIt()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base.DoIt was called!");
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public override void DoIt()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived.DoIt was called!");
    }
}

public class Derived1 : Derived
{
    public new void DoIt()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived1.DoIt was called!");
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Base b = new Derived();
        Derived d = new Derived();
        Console.WriteLine("#1");
        b.DoIt();                      
        Console.WriteLine("#2");
        d.DoIt();                     
        b = new Derived1();
        d = new Derived1();
        Console.WriteLine("#3");
        b.DoIt();                    
        Console.WriteLine("#4");
        d.DoIt();
        Console.WriteLine("#5");
        Derived1 e = new Derived1();
        e.DoIt();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```